# How to convert lat lng in the format for gt06

Tags: flutter, traccar

I am new to flutter and I am trying to convert lat lng to this format

Format Length(Byte)
Start Bit 2
Packet Length 1
Protocol Number 1
Information Content N
Information Serial Number 2
Error Check 2
Stop Bit 2

I have written this function but this isn't working.

```
  String convertCoordinatesToFormat(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // Start Bit (2 bytes)
    String startBit = (0x78.toString()) ;

    // Protocol Number (1 byte)
    int protocolNumber = 0x22; // Replace with the appropriate protocol number

    // Information Content (N bytes)
    // Convert latitude and longitude to the desired format, e.g., as strings
    String latitudeString = latitude.toStringAsFixed(6); // Replace with the desired precision for latitude
    String longitudeString = longitude.toStringAsFixed(6); // Replace with the desired precision for longitude
    String informationContent = "$latitudeString$longitudeString";

    // Calculate the length in bytes
    int length = 5 + informationContent.length ~/ 2; // Divide by 2 since each byte is represented by 2 characters in hexadecimal

    // Length (1 byte)
    String lengthString = length.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0");

    // Packet Length (1 byte)
    // int packetLength = lengthString; // Length of the remaining bytes (Protocol Number + Information Content + Information Serial Number + Error Check + Stop Bit)

    // Information Serial Number (2 bytes)
    int informationSerialNumber = 1; // Replace with the appropriate serial number


    // Error Check (2 bytes)
    int errorCheck = calculateErrorCheck(informationContent);
    String errorCheckString = errorCheck.toRadixString(16).padLeft(4, "0");

    // Stop Bit (2 bytes)
    String stopBit = (0x0D.toString()) + (0x0A.toString());

    // Concatenate all the fields together
    String result = "$startBit$lengthString$protocolNumber$informationContent$informationSerialNumber$errorCheckString$stopBit";

    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(result);
    String answer = "";
    for (int a in bytes){
      answer += a.toString();
    }

    // Convert the formatted coordinates to uppercase
    return answer;
  }

  int calculateErrorCheck(String content) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      sum += content.codeUnitAt(i);
    }
    return sum % 65536;
  }
```

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to explain what you think is wrong with your effort and show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant part of the source code from Traccar GPS server (Java):

```
    DateBuilder dateBuilder = new DateBuilder(timezone)
            .setDate(buf.readUnsignedByte(), buf.readUnsignedByte(), buf.readUnsignedByte())
            .setTime(buf.readUnsignedByte(), buf.readUnsignedByte(), buf.readUnsignedByte());
    position.setTime(dateBuilder.getDate());

    if (hasLength && buf.readUnsignedByte() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (hasSatellites) {
        position.set(Position.KEY_SATELLITES, BitUtil.to(buf.readUnsignedByte(), 4));
    }

    double latitude = buf.readUnsignedInt() / 60.0 / 30000.0;
    double longitude = buf.readUnsignedInt() / 60.0 / 30000.0;

    if (hasSpeed) {
        position.setSpeed(UnitsConverter.knotsFromKph(buf.readUnsignedByte()));
    }

    int flags = buf.readUnsignedShort();
    position.setCourse(BitUtil.to(flags, 10));
    position.setValid(BitUtil.check(flags, 12));

    if (!BitUtil.check(flags, 10)) {
        latitude = -latitude;
    }
    if (BitUtil.check(flags, 11)) {
        longitude = -longitude;
    }

    position.setLatitude(latitude);
    position.setLongitude(longitude);
```

Full source code for the GT06 decoder is [here](https://github.com/traccar/traccar/blob/master/src/main/java/org/traccar/protocol/Gt06ProtocolDecoder.java).

Note that it is using Netty library, so the snippet is using Netty `ByteBuf`.